# How to modify JavaScript to calculate Girl Scouts Cookie "cases" instead of "packages" (12 packages = 1 case)

Tags: javascript, calculator

Our Girl Scout Cookie Calculator (https://cookiecalculator.org/) would better serve our members if it was able to calculate in number of "cases" instead of "packages" (12 packages = 1 case). How can I modify the JavaScript to accomplish this? The correct results we want is; 2 cases of gf input at the top should result in 2 cases in the output at the cookie variety list. (see screenshot)
[Image highlighting how correct calculation should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzMo9.png)

I tried removing the `*12` from the following JavaScript code, but unsuccessful in getting the right calculations.

```
    $('.totalPkgNum').html(Math.floor(troopCases)*12);
    $('.finalPkgNum').html(Math.floor(troopCases)*12);
    $('.totalCasesNum').html(Math.floor(troopCases));
};
```

```
FULL JAVASCRIPT minus full troop PGA values because that list goes on and on and on.

/**
 * Created by casie (vendor) on 9/22/16.
 */
/**
 * Updated by Natalie Gove on 10/07/22.
 */
var cookieArray = [
    {"variety": "Adventurefuls", "popularity": .11, "order": 0, "class": "adv", "image": "images/cookies/C_ADV.png"},
    {"variety": "Toast Yay", "popularity": .052, "order": 1, "class": "ty", "image": "images/cookies/C_TY3.png"},
    {"variety": "Lemonades", "popularity": .092, "order": 2, "class": "lm", "image": "images/cookies/C_LM3.png"},
    {"variety": "Shortbread", "popularity": .063, "order": 3, "class": "sb", "image": "images/cookies/C_SB3.png"},
    {"variety": "Peanut Butter Patties", "popularity": .145, "order": 4, "class": "pbp", "image": "images/cookies/C_PBP3.png"},
    {"variety": "Caramel deLites", "popularity": .205, "order": 5, "class": "cd", "image": "images/cookies/C_CD3.png"},
    {"variety": "Peanut Butter Sandwich", "popularity": .068, "order": 6, "class": "pbs", "image": "images/cookies/C_PBS3.png"},
    {"variety": "Caramel Chocolate Chip (gluten-free)", "order": 7, "class": "trio", "image": "images/cookies/C_GFCCC.png"},
    {"variety": "Thin Mints", "order": 8, "class": "tm", "image": "images/cookies/C_TM3.png"}
];

var grandTotal = 0;
var PGA = 0;
var glutenFree = 0;
var glutenFree2 = 0;
var numGirls = 0;
var numGirls2 = 0;
var troopNumber = 0;
var packagesTroop = 0;
var troopCases = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    appendData(glutenFree);
    $('.returningTroop').on('click', function(){
        $('.formReturningTroop').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.tableRow').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.bottomImage').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.firstCopyReturn').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.secondCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.thirdCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.cookieGraph').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.printReturn').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.buttons').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    });

    $('.newTroop').on('click', function(){
        $('.formNewTroop').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.tableRow').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.bottomImage').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.firstCopyNew').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.secondCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.thirdCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.cookieGraph').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.printNew').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
        $('.buttons').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    });

    $('.submit').on('click', newTroop);
    $('.submit2').on('click', returningTroop);

    $('.printNew').on('click', createPrintNew);
    $('.printReturn').on('click', createPrintReturn);
});



//New Troop function
var newTroop = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    resetArrayVal();
    level = $(".level").val();
    numGirls = parseInt($(".numGirls").val());
    if(!numGirls){
        numGirls = 0;
    };
    cookieArray[7].order = parseInt($(".glutenFree").val());
    calculatePGA(level);
    packagesPerTroop(PGA, numGirls);
    casesPerTroop(packagesTroop, glutenFree);
    calculateCookiePercent(troopCases, glutenFree, numGirls);
    appendData();
    $('.finalCookieView').show();
};

//Returning Troop function
var returningTroop = function(event){
    resetArrayVal();
    event.preventDefault();
    troopNumber = $(".troopNumber").val();
    if(!troopNumber){
        troopNumber = 0;
    };
    numGirls2 = parseInt($('.numGirls2').val());
    if(!numGirls2){
        numGirls2 = 0;
    };
    console.log(numGirls2);
    cookieArray[7].order = parseInt($(".glutenFree2").val());
    calculatePGAajax(troopNumber, numGirls2, glutenFree2)
};

//AJAX request to JSON file to find out PGA for specific troop
var calculatePGAajax = function(troopNumber, numGirls){
    var test;
    troops = jsonData;
        for (var i = 0; i < troops.length; i++) {
            if (troops[i].Troop == troopNumber) {
                test = troops[i].Troop;
                PGA = troops[i].PGA;
                console.log(PGA);
            }
        }
        if(test != troopNumber){
            alert("Troop not found, contact girlscouts@girlscoutsrv.org for assistance.")
        }
        packagesPerTroop(PGA, numGirls);
        casesPerTroop(packagesTroop);
        calculateCookiePercent(troopCases, numGirls);
        appendData();
};

//calculates the PGA to use
var calculatePGA = function(level){
    if(level === 'daisy') {
        PGA = 170;
    }else if(level === 'brownie'){
        PGA = 185;
    }else if(level === 'junior') {
        PGA = 220;
    }else if(level === 'cadette') {
        PGA = 225;
    }else if (level === 'senior') {
        PGA = 210;
    }else if(level === 'ambassador') {
        PGA = 215;
    }
    console.log("PGA, ", PGA);
    return PGA;
};

var packagesPerTroop = function(PGA, numGirls){
    packagesTroop = PGA * numGirls;
    console.log("packages per troop , ", packagesTroop)
};

//calculates the number of cases for the specific troop minus GF
var casesPerTroop = function(packagesTroop){
    troopCases = packagesTroop / 12;
    console.log("cases per troop, ", troopCases);
};


//calculates how many cases to order of each cookie - percentages come from the GSRV
var calculateCookiePercent = function(troopCases, numGirls, PGA, packagesTroop) {
    var i = troopCases - cookieArray[7].order;
    console.log("total cases minus GF, ", i);
    var summation = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < cookieArray.length-2; j++){
        cookieArray[j].order = Math.round(i * cookieArray[j].popularity);
        console.log(cookieArray[j].variety, cookieArray[j].order);
        summation += cookieArray[j].order;
    }
    summation += cookieArray[7].order;
    console.log("all cases plus gluten free, ", summation);
    cookieArray[8].order = Math.floor(troopCases - summation);
    console.log("thin mints order, ", cookieArray[8].order)
};

//append data to the DOM
var appendData = function() {
    $el = $('.finalCookieView');
    $el.empty();
    $el.append("<tr><th class='leftTH'>Cookie Variety</th><th class='rightTH'>Packages</th></tr>");
    $el.append("<tbody></tbody>");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length-5; i++) {
        $el.last().append("<tr class='" + cookieArray[i].class + "'><td class='left'><img src='" + cookieArray[i].image + "'/><p>" + cookieArray[i].variety + "</p></td><td class='right'>" + (cookieArray[i].order*12) + "</td></tr><tr><td><td></td></td></tr>");
    }

    $el.last().append("<tr class='" + cookieArray[8].class + "'><td class='left'><img src='" + cookieArray[8].image + "'/><p>" + cookieArray[8].variety + "</p></td><td class='right'>" + (cookieArray[8].order*12) + "</td></tr><tr><td><td></td></td></tr>");

    for (var j = 4; j < cookieArray.length-1; j++) {
        $el.last().append("<tr class='" + cookieArray[j].class + "'><td class='left'><img src='" + cookieArray[j].image + "'/><p>" + cookieArray[j].variety + "</p></td><td class='right'>" + (cookieArray[j].order*12) + "</td></tr><tr><td><td></td></td></tr>");
    }

    $('.totalPkgNum').html(Math.floor(troopCases)*12);
    $('.finalPkgNum').html(Math.floor(troopCases)*12);
    $('.totalCasesNum').html(Math.floor(troopCases));
};


var resetArrayVal = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++){
        cookieArray[i].order = 0;
        grandTotal = 0;
    }
};

var createPrintReturn = function() {
    $('.formReturningTroop').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.firstCopyReturn').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.bottomImage').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.buttons').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.boxImage').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.firstCopy').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.secondCopy').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.thirdCopy').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.cookieGraph').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    window.print();
    $('.formReturningTroop').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.firstCopyReturn').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.bottomImage').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.boxImage').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.firstCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.secondCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.thirdCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.cookieGraph').addClass('formTroopHidden');
};

var createPrintNew = function() {
    $('.formNewTroop').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.firstCopyNew').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.bottomImage').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.buttons').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.boxImage').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.firstCopy').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.secondCopy').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.thirdCopy').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.cookieGraph').addClass('formTroopHidden');
    window.print();
    $('.formNewTroop').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.firstCopyNew').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.bottomImage').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.boxImage').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.firstCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.secondCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.thirdCopy').removeClass('formTroopHidden');
    $('.cookieGraph').addClass('formTroopHidden');
};


var jsonData = [
 {
   "Troop": 736,
   "PGA": 107
 },
 {
   "Troop": 1626,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 3279,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 4336,
   "PGA": 78
 },
 {
   "Troop": 5061,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 5237,
   "PGA": 102
 },
 {
   "Troop": 9193,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 10041,
   "PGA": 121
 },
 {
   "Troop": 10398,
   "PGA": 159
 },
 {
   "Troop": 10811,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 11794,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 11881,
   "PGA": 166
 },
 {
   "Troop": 11951,
   "PGA": 155
 },
 {
   "Troop": 12124,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 12760,
   "PGA": 250
 },
 {
   "Troop": 12911,
   "PGA": 81
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13023,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13306,
   "PGA": 238
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13419,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13426,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13440,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13538,
   "PGA": 61
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13555,
   "PGA": 220
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13565,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13575,
   "PGA": 210
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13722,
   "PGA": 90
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13759,
   "PGA": 1
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13780,
   "PGA": 54
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13876,
   "PGA": 94
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13906,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 13909,
   "PGA": 45
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14071,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14079,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14177,
   "PGA": 60
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14178,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14200,
   "PGA": 182
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14201,
   "PGA": 176
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14210,
   "PGA": 141
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14221,
   "PGA": 146
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14222,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14286,
   "PGA": 126
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14296,
   "PGA": 188
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14335,
   "PGA": 290
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14341,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14353,
   "PGA": 298
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14354,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14355,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14373,
   "PGA": 192
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14405,
   "PGA": 7
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14420,
   "PGA": 223
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14450,
   "PGA": 54
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14478,
   "PGA": 133
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14508,
   "PGA": 53
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14512,
   "PGA": 134
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14513,
   "PGA": 129
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14514,
   "PGA": 300
 },
 {
   "Troop": 14515,
   "PGA": 300
 },

...
```

Comment: What did you get instead of "the right calculations"?

Comment: The correct results we want is; 2 cases of gf input at the top should result in 2 cases in the output at the cookie variety list.

Comment: For a [good question](/help/how-to-ask), please remember to post a [mcve], not your full code. A cookie array with one entry shows things off just fine, same for that jsonData, it doesn't need a million entries, and same for a _lot_ of the other code: barely any of it is actually necessary to illustrate/demonstrate the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Does this mean that "# of Gluten-Free" input === Caramel Chocolate Chip (gluten-free) packages no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change following, but it's an absolute shot in the dark.

```js
$el.last().append("<tr class='" + cookieArray[8].class + "'><td class='left'><img src='" + cookieArray[8].image + "'/><p>" + cookieArray[8].variety + "</p></td><td class='right'>" + (cookieArray[8].order*12) + "</td></tr><tr><td><td></td></td></tr>");
```

To this:

```js
$el.last().append("<tr class='" + cookieArray[8].class + "'><td class='left'><img src='" + cookieArray[8].image + "'/><p>" + cookieArray[8].variety + "</p></td><td class='right'>" + (cookieArray[8].order) + "</td></tr><tr><td><td></td></td></tr>");
```